# Способы выполнять запросы без использования ASyncTask

Tags: android, java, httpclient

Доброго времени суток.

Недавно дописал клиент для сайта, в котором вся работа с сетью была возложена на `ASyncTask`, т.е. при создании активности создавался экземпляр класса, в котором выполнялся запрос к серверу, запускалась вторая задача, которая в фоне получала результат работы первой задачи, а дальше в `UI` потоке использовались полученные данные. Подобного рода  архитектура приложения не совсем адекватная (как и говорилось на `Google IO (2010)`), ибо активность не всегда удавалось уничтожить, если задача была не до конца выполнена. В таком случае приложение вообще напрочь переставало работать, а именно, отправлять запросы к серверу. Немного погуглив, натолкнулся на неплохую [статью](http://neilgoodman.net/2012/01/01/modern-techniques-for-implementing-rest-clients-on-android-4-0-and-below-part-2/), где отправка запросов шла из `Service`'а, в котором содержимое метода `onHandleIntent()` выполнялось в отдельном потоке при каждом вызове этого метода. Данная в статье архитектура приложения, к сожалению, мне не подошла (работают у меня все адаптеры и т.д. с объектами `HashMap<String, String> и ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`, которые вернуть не получается, ибо их надо как-то положить в Bundle)).

Потому возникает вопрос: какие еще есть способы выполнять запросы, работая с вышеперечисленными типами данных, при том без использования `ASyncTask`?

p.s. заранее спасибо

Comment: мало вы изучили возможности класса Bundle.
он может хранить все, что реализует интерфейс Serializable и Parcelable

Comment: спасибо, пойду-ка покопаюсь))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть еще такой паттерн, когда данные из сети (неважно каким образом - или через `Runnable` или `AsyncTask` или `IntentService`) загружаются в БД. Над БД натянут `ContentProvider`, который через `CursorLoader` автоматом подгружает данные в `Activity` `CursorAdapter`'ом

Изюминка способа заключается в том, что асинхронность загрузки данных влияет только на БД, соответственно наличие/отсутствие `Activity` и вообще UI треда не играет роли для загрузчика данных. А как только UI тред появляется, то `CursorAdapter` обеспечивает его отображение на юай морду. Грубо говоря, границей между нестабильным UI и не менее нестабильным загрузчиком является БД.

Comment: Ага, где-то видал такую схемку) На днях снова поищу, спасибо.
(видимо зря бросил, так и не поняв реализации)